# C++ How to convert substring to int

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, substring

What is printed to the console:

```
START(0,0)
GOAL(0,2)
ooox
xxoo
ooox
```

I want to be able to store the `START` and `GOAL` points as integers from a substring since what is printed onto the console are read from an external file.

I am making an application to traverse the 2D grid, where the `x` represents the blocked paths and `o` represents unblocked.

I have tried using `.substr()` to take only the parts of the string containing the coordinate pairs, and `std::stoi()` to convert the String type into an Int.

```
void Grid::loadFromFile(const std::string& filename){
     std::string line, startPoint, goalPoint;
     std::vector<std::string> grid;
     int startX, startY, goalX, goalY;

     std::ifstream file(filename);

     if (!file.is_open()) return;

     if (!std::getline(file, line)) return;

     if (line.compare(0, 5, "START") != 0) return;

     startPoint = line.substr(6,3);

     startX = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(1,1));
     startY = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(2,2));

     if (!std::getline(file, line)) return;

     if (line.compare(0, 4, "GOAL") != 0) return;

     goalPoint = line.substr(5,3);

     goalX = std::stoi(goalPoint.substr(1,1));
     goalY = std::stoi(goalPoint.substr(2,2));

     test = line.substr(7,1);

     while (std::getline(file, line)) {
          grid.push_back(line);
     }

     file.close();

     std::cout << "Start: " << startPoint << "\n";
     std::cout << "Goal: " << goalPoint << "\n";
     std::cout << "Start X: " << startX << "\n";
     std::cout << "Start Y: " << startY << "\n";
     std::cout << "Goal X: " << goalX << "\n";
     std::cout << "Goal Y: " << goalY << std::endl;
}
```

The expected outcome of the code is to print the correct `startX/Y` & `goalX/Y` values.

The results I get:

```
Start: 0,0
Goal: 0,2
Start X: 1
Start Y: 162010192
Goal X: 0
Goal Y: 1543563378
```

I don't know why I get the values that are returned as they are random and make no sense to me as to how I have obtained those values.

Comment: So when you got out your debugger and stepped through the program, what arguments were you passing to stoi?

Comment: Have you checked what `startPoint.substr(2,2)` yields?

Comment: You do a single getline(), then check for "START" and then assume the next line will get read somehow. In fact, you need a second getline()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading a string, then using `substr` to pull out the pieces you care about, I'd prefer to specify the expected input format a little more directly. In C, I'd probably have done something like this:

```
if (fscanf(infile, "START(%d,%d)", &startX, &startY) != 2)
   // error in reading start point

if (fscanf(infile, "GOAL(%d,%d)", &goalX, &goalY) != 2)
    // error reading goal point
```

In C++, at least to me it seems to me like the code we'd really like to write is something on this order:

```
input >> "START(">> startX >> "," >> startY >> ")\n";
input >> "GOAL(">> goalX >> "," >> goalY > ")\n";
```

So, at least as I see things, the question is whether (and if so how) we can support that. The answer is yes we can (probably pretty obvious--it would be pretty pointless to do a big build-up, then say "sorry, but we can't do that").

To support that, we need an extractor for constant strings. At its simplest, it might look something like this:

```
template <class charT>
std::basic_istream<charT> &operator>>(std::basic_istream<charT> &is, charT const *fmt) {
    while (*fmt) {
        if (*fmt != is.peek())
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        ++fmt;
        is.ignore(1);
    }
    return is;
}
```

So, this basically just looks at one character at a time from the input stream, compares it to the current character from the format string. If they match, it just extracts that character from the stream and goes to the next. If they don't match, it sets the fail bit to say the extraction failed.

That has one shortcoming: a stream has a `skipws` bit, and if it's set, we expect to skip white space before attempting to do anything else. That should probably apply here, so something like `infile >> "ignore"` would match input like "   ignore".

To fix that, we could add a little loop something like this:

```
while (std::isspace(is.peek()))
    is.ignore(1);
```

...before trying to match the string. That has another shortcoming though: it always uses the current global `locale`--but a stream can be imbued with its own `locale`, which should apply to reading from that stream. So, to skip white space properly, we should retrieve the stream's `locale`, then get the `ctype` facet from that `locale`, and use it to decide whether something is white space or not. Unfortunately, the code to do that is a little longer and more complex than anybody probably likes:

```
template <class charT>
std::basic_istream<charT> &operator>>(std::basic_istream<charT> &is, charT const *fmt) {
    if (fmt == nullptr)
        return is;

    if (is.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws) {
        std::locale const &loc = is.getloc();
        if (std::has_facet<std::ctype<charT>>(loc)) {
            auto const &ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<charT>>(loc);
            while (ct.is(std::ctype_base::blank, is.peek()))
                is.ignore(1);
        }
        else
            while (std::isspace(is.peek()))
                is.ignore(1);
    }

    while (*fmt) {
        if (*fmt != is.peek())
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        ++fmt;
        is.ignore(1);
    }
    return is;
}
```

At least for the moment, I've written this so it retrieves the stream's `locale`, and uses its `ctype` facet if it has one, but if it has a `locale` with no ctype facet (which is at least theoretically possible) it falls back to using `std::isspace` to decide whether something is white space. There's probably room for argument that it would be better to just fail at that point, but I'll leave that question for another day.

Once we're done, we can read things like we wanted to though:

```
int main() { 
    std::istringstream b("START(0, 0)\nGOAL(1,2)");

    int startX, startY;
    b >> "START(" >> startX >> "," >> startY >> ")";
    std::cout << "start_x: " << startX << ", start_y: " << startY << "\n";

    int goalX, goalY;
    b >> "GOAL(" >> goalX >> "," >> goalY >> ")";
    std::cout << "goal_x: " << goalX << ", goal_y: " << goalY << "\n";
}
```

Note that the behavior here is still slightly different than `scanf` and company's. In particular, this will skip white space before the beginning of the format string you specify (if `skipws` is set), then attempt to match each character in the string you pass literally.

By contrast, `scanf` and company treat any white space in your format string as a directive to skip a run of all consecutive white space in the input. You can (of course) change this to act like `scanf` and company if you want--but that behavior seems to surprise quite a few people, so I *think* it's probably better the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
startX = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(1,1));
startY = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(2,2));
```

to

```
startX = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(0,1));
startY = std::stoi(startPoint.substr(2,1));
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

`substr` has two arguments: position and length of the substring.

The same applies for your goal points.

Comment: My advice would be to post confident answers and eliminate terms like "My guess". You should post answers if you are confident they are correct and avoid answers that might not be correct. If you need more information you can try posting a comment on the question asking for it.